# Django changing field which has been created by extra

Tags: python, django

Is there any option to change the filed which has been created by .extra method?

I have this:

```
self.x = MyModel.objects.extra(
        select={
        "year": "date_trunc('year', created)",
        }
    )
#I have field 'year'

for i in self.x:
    i.year = datetime.datetime(1999,1,1,1,1)
    i.save()
#I changed this field


# but here....
self.x = self.x.values('year').annotate(
            Sum('clicked'))
# field 'year' has the same value as at the beginning.
```

Can I change this field?

Comment: Django version? I I think it is a problem related to the transaction. Read about this in [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/transactions/](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/transactions/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly change the value of that extra field. That's created in a temporary relation and handed to you as a result of calculating `date_trunc('year', created)` for each record, but not stored in the database.

If you want to change the value of the `extra` query, you would have to change the attribute it's calculated on.

Since that's the `created` attribute, I would guess you don't want ot change that, so your best bet might be to have a year attribute defined on the model and handle its calculation and storage entirely within Python and Django, rather than through an extra query.